# How to reuse a specific RewriteRule request [.htaccess]

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Hello,**

I've a problem with my .htaccess file, i can't reuse a specific RewriteRule  request :/ 
Do you have a solution to this ? :(

**my code:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$                 app/views/routes.php?page=user&scate=$1
RewriteRule ^user/homepage/(.*)$        app/views/routes.php?page=user&scate=homepage&user=$1
```

Thanks you and sorry for my english, i'm french

Comment: Provide an example of what you mean. What is `i can't reuse a specific RewriteRule request`?

Comment: hmmm, to access the file like this: "http://example.com/user/homepage/Eklopsis" and "http://example.com/user/" ... I do not know how to say